# Vertical Alignment in Table using Array Not Working

Tags: tables

See below for my code. I did not change anything with the code, but just re-compiled my LaTeX document and the vertical center alignment is no longer functioning.

How can I get the vertical center alignment (as seen in the 'before' screenshot) back?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| L{3cm} | L{8cm} | L{1.7cm} | L{1.7cm} |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Section} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Available Points} & \textbf{Earned Points}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Cover Page} & Includes the title of the report, team name, and all of the team member names. & 1 & ~\\[1cm]
        \hline
        \textbf{Introduction} & Explains the project functionality and features. & 2 & ~\\[1cm]
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work for me either. I propose to modify the definition of your column types to incorporate the `S` pre-specifier (you can use another letter if you load`siunitx`) from `cellspace`. This ensures in the corresponding columns a minimal vertical spacing at the top and at the bottom of the cells:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2ex}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2ex}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{m{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{m{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}S{m{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| L{3cm} |L{8cm} | L{1.7cm} | L{1.7cm} |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Section} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Available Points} & \textbf{Earned Points}\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Cover Page} & Includes the title of the report, team name, and all of the team member names. & 1 & ~\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Introduction} & Explains the project functionality and features. & 2 & ~\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @lemontwist: Could  you post an example code which doesn't work?